# custom hover effect position issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a button 10px off the horizontal center of the screen. This is the button code. The button uses some fancy hovering effect, which doesn't move with the button. How can I put the button 10px off the horizontal center of the screen?

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 40px 50px;
}
.button-2 a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.eff-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button-2:hover .eff-2 {
  top: 0;
}
.button-2:hover a {
  color: #666;
}
.watch-video-position {}
```

```html
<div class="watch-video-position">
  <div class="button-2 watch-video-position">
    <div class="eff-2 watch-video-position"></div>
    <a href="#"> CLICK ME </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "10px off the horizontal center of the screen", do you mean you want the button's center to be 10px to the right/left of the center of the screen, or the button's left edge, or the button's right edge? Please provide additional detail so we can understand the exact behaviour you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks mate, you can ask me for any more information needed, related to the way it needs to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
.top {
  position: relative;
}
.top .button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
```

Make sure you add the unique class `top` to the first `<div>` and use that to position. You can also use margin and padding on the `.top`.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 40px 50px;
}
.button-2 a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.eff-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button-2:hover .eff-2 {
  top: 0;
}
.button-2:hover a {
  color: #666;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.top .button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top watch-video-position">
  <div class="button-2 watch-video-position">
    <div class="eff-2 watch-video-position"></div>
    <a href="#"> CLICK ME </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
I have made some changes in the css to class button-2.
.button-2 {
      float: none;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 10px;
    }
```

```css
body {
      background-color: green;
    }
    .button-2 {
      border: 2px solid white;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: none;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      top: 10px;
      width: 140px;
    }
    .button-2 a {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 50px;
      transition: all .5s ease;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
    .eff-2 {
      width: 140px;
      height: 50px;
      top: -50px;
      background: white;
      position: absolute;
      transition: all .5s ease;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .button-2:hover .eff-2 {
      top: 0;
    }
    .button-2:hover a {
      color: #666;
    }
    .watch-video-position {}
```

```html
<div class="watch-video-position">
      <div class="button-2 watch-video-position">
        <div class="eff-2 watch-video-position"></div>
        <a href="#"> CLICK ME </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try centering its parent and shifting it within its parent:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.button-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 40px 50px;
}
.button-2 a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.eff-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button-2:hover .eff-2 {
  top: 0;
}
.button-2:hover a {
  color: #666;
}
.watch-video-position {}
```

```html
<div class="watch-video-position outer">
  <div class="button-2 watch-video-position">
    <div class="eff-2 watch-video-position"></div>
    <a href="#"> CLICK ME </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't you see a blue div centered and then the "Click me" div shifted to the right?

Comment: Yes, why did the blue div coming in? I was telling that.

Comment: it seems I did not get your concern, I though you wanted to "almost-center" it, and the blue div is to make visible the fact that the "Click me" is shifted to the right, but almost centered (since its parent does remain centered at all times)

Comment: Fine. I understood. My solution has dead centred it... :)

Comment: Thanks man! This works great! Do you mind adding which style performs off-centering?

Comment: @sanjihan the blue .outer div is centered, and the .button-2 has assimetric margins

Answer (score 1):

try width 90% of div.button-2 and set border and padding to anchor.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-2 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;      
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 40px 50px;
}
.button-2 a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding:15px;
}
.eff-2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button-2:hover .eff-2 {
  top: 0;
}
.button-2:hover a {
  color: #666;
}
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.top .button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top watch-video-position">
  <div class="button-2 watch-video-position">
    <div class="eff-2 watch-video-position"></div>
    <a href="#"> CLICK ME </a>
  </div>
</div>
```